# Devexpress XtraReport Duplicate Items In Detail Band

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I am using DevExpress Winforms XtraReports in my application for reporting purposes. The problem is whenever I insert an item, for example lets say an XRLabel, in the designer, I will then see this XRLabel twice in preview mode. This occurs when I insert the XRLabel into the Details band.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the detail band will show for each record which matches the criteria you have entered. So if your report brings back 10 items, it will show a new detail row for each item displaying the label in each detail row. To overcome this issue put the label into a Group or Report or Page header so that it will only display at the top of the columns be it once for each new Group, each Page or just once for the whole report.